# MATLAB logical image uint8 image multiplication

Tags: matlab

I have two images. 1st one is with data type uint8. 2nd one with data type logical. I want to multiply these two images so that I can replace the "1" values of 2nd image by the intensity values of 1st image. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to call the image `img` and the logical matrix `mask` and assume same size. Using [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) you can do

```
img(~mask) = 0;
```

which should be faster than multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

I assume both images have the same size.

Then you can just do a element-wise multiplication `.*`, but you obviously first have to conver to the same type, so that would result in following code:

```
uint8_image .* uint8(logical_image)
```